# from django.utils import translation not working on shell

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am using Django translation for the first time, Please help me to fix the issue. According to the Django doc for translation 
[Using translations outside views and templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/translation/#using-translations-outside-views-and-templates) I have tried below code on shell but unfortunately thats not working:

```
>>> from django.utils import translation

>>> def welcome_translated(language):
        cur_language = translation.get_language()
        try:
            translation.activate(language)
            text = translation.gettext('welcome')
        finally:
            translation.activate(cur_language)
        return text

>>> translation.get_language()
'en'
>>> welcome_translated('fa-ir')
'welcome'
```

Comment: Do you have a language file for 'fa-ir'? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/translation/#localization-how-to-create-language-files

Comment: If am not wrong language file is used to translate static text (please correct me if am wrong). Is this not possible without language file?  Actually I want to translate dynamic data which user post and could translate the same later. How would I perform this?

Comment: You need a language file. From the link that you provided in the OP
`The Django translation mechanisms can be used to translate arbitrary texts to any language that is supported by Django (as long as an appropriate translation catalog exists, of course)`